# Cant add item to ListView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Hello I have this code in C# to get the files and list them in `ListView` but nothing happens

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("plugins/");
foreach (string file in files)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
    item.Tag = file;
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    listView1.Items.Add(item);

}
```

I even tried to insert a different one with single line of code

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
listView1.Items.Add("item");
```

but it does not add the item
Thank You

Comment: Move listView1.Items.Clear(); and place it before foreach...

Comment: it does not work :(

Comment: Clear listview before foreach loop. You are clearing the list before each file is added.

Comment: Please provide a clear description of your problem ("does not work" is not) and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the last part

Comment: Which UI framework is that? WinForms? Which .NET version are you targetting?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: What is the type of listView1?

Comment: what do you mean it is the default component of .net

Comment: listView1 is a (member?) variable in your code, but it could be of any type. Please include the definition of listView1 in your question.

Comment: listView1 is on the form

Comment: Seeing the answers and your answers to those answers (xD)... could it be that you "files" array is not getting populated?

Comment: wait what?.....

Comment: put a breakpoint here :    `string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);` and see if it reaches it, and if it does, what is the value of 'file'

Comment: nope :( ..........

Comment: Can you show your html code ?

Comment: this is C# not html

Comment: OP means to say its WinForms...

Comment: that's because `Directory.GetFiles("plugins/");` doesn't return anything, or that plugins directory doesn't exist, or it's trying to find it in the wrong place. Try with `Directory.GetFiles("/plugins");` instead, maybe? Or put directly the whole path (C:\myfiles\blabla\plugins for example)

Comment: no items :((((( it does not work it does not add it

Comment: so that's it...

Comment: In which method are you calling the code you posted?

Comment: wait ?????????? what do you mean

Comment: if your `string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);` does not contain any value then how its bind your list, first correct your path which your define to get you file from defined directory then it would be work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListViewItem.Tag is the only property you are setting and that property is not going to be visible in the UI.  Try this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("plugins/");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
                item.Text= file;
                listView1.Items.Add(item);

            }
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ListViewItem' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'ListViewItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Documentation says it does, maybe you're on a different version.  Is there a property called Text?

Comment: How do you know?  Is it that you don't see them in the UI, or you step through in debugger and it's not adding anything to the listview1.Items? What if you do item.Text = "DOES THIS WORK"?

Comment: i debug it and it does not do anything listview is blank

Answer (score 0):

This code in your foreach loop:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
```

always clears the list view everytime the foreach statement is executed leaving you with only 1 item added in the view after the execution of the foreach statement.

I suggest removing that. If you need to need to clear it out, create a method that will clear the list and call the method somewhere, but should not definitely be in the foreach statement.

Your instantiation of the list view must not be in the foreach loop. You may instantiate it on the method level or in the class level so that your separate method that will clear the items in the list will be able to reference it.

```
class Program
{
    static ListView listView1 = new ListView();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\testfiles");

        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
            item.Tag = file;
            listView1.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }

    static void ClearList()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("plugins/");
        string fileName = "";
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
            var item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Tag = file;
            item.Text = fileName;
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'file' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry now try it.

Comment: it does not add the item to the listView :(

Comment: have you check your file ? what contains it ?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: debug your foreach loop and check your file varaible what it contains ?